# Multiple ComboBox with unique choice Powershell

Tags: powershell, user-interface

Hi guys i'm coding a GUI. I have multiples comboboxes and i would like to do something like this, I know that you can do this with a textbox :

```
$checkbox1 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.checkbox
$checkbox1.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(60,50)
$checkbox1.Text = "Sample"
$checkbox1.Checked = $false
$checkbox1.CheckedChanged({
    $checkbox1.Checked = $checkbox2.Disabled
    $checkbox1.Checked = $checkbox3.Disable 
})
$mainfrm.Controls.Add($checkbox1)
```

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$checkbox1.Add_CheckStateChanged({checkBox_CheckedChanged($value=1)})
function checkBox_CheckedChanged(){ 
switch($value){
           "1"{
                  if ($checkBox1.Checked)
                  {
                    $checkBox2.Enabled = $false
                    $checkBox3.Enabled = $false
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    $checkBox2.Enabled = $true
                    $checkBox3.Enabled = $true
                  }
               } and etc...
```

If anyone needs